# MySQL slow queries aren't logged

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, query-optimization

In my CentOS machine I use MySQL 5.5.30. (I rented server two days ago and I'm newbie in Linux commands)

I'm trying to check for slow MySQL queries. So I made this from phpMyAdmin

```
SET GLOBAL log_slow_queries = ON;
SET GLOBAL slow_launch_time = 1;
FLUSH LOGS;
```

And in default configuration `slow query log file` variable is `/var/lib/mysql/srv1-slow.log`

But when I check `/var/` folder with FTP, there exists only `/var/tmp/` folder. which is empty. What should I do more to see slow queries log?

Note: I tried to create `/var/lib` folder but system didn't let me.

Answer (score 5):

Add following lines in `/etc/my.cnf` and restart mysql:

**Notes:** In my case MySQL version is 5.0.x

```
[mysqld]

    log-slow-queries = /var/lib/mysql/sev1-slow.log
    long_query_time = 1
```

In MySQL 5.5 version

```
[mysqld]

    slow_query_log_file= = /var/lib/mysql/sev1-slow.log
    long_query_time = 1
    slow_query_log = 1
```

You must create the file manually and change owners this way:

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
touch /var/lib/mysql/sev1-slow.log
chown mysql.mysql -R /var/lib/mysql
```